# Weierstrass theorem to prove Slutsky's lemma

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $(Y_n)_{n\ge 1}$ and $(Z_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be two sequences of random variables defined on the same space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P}).$

> There is Slutsky's lemma which states:
>
> $$Y_n\overset{D}\to Y\;\mbox{and}\; Z_n\overset{P}\to c\; \mbox{then}\; (Y_n,Z_n)\overset{D}\to( Y,c).$$
>
> which means that foor all $h\in C_b(\Bbb{R}^2),\quad\Bbb{E}h(Y_n,Z_n)\overset{n\to\infty}\to \Bbb{E} h(Y,c).$

The proof starts by saying it is sufficient to consider $h$ as $h(y,z)=f(y)g(z).$

It doesn't seem trivial at all? I know that for the convergence in distribution it's enough to prove the convergence in a space $\mathcal{H}$ that is total in $C_0(\Bbb{R}).$

Perhaps we can use this idea with Weierstrass theorem but we need compact space, perhaps using Alexandroff one-point compactification for $\Bbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Not that it's relevant, but lols at the name Slutsky.

Comment: @stressed-out that's why I formulate it in my question :p.

Comment: Look for "Locally Compact Stone -Weierstrass Theorem".

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks I will look at it

Comment: Since $(Y_n,Z_n)$ is tight, it is enough to consider compactly supported functions. The latter can be approximated by linear combinations of functions of the form $f(x)g(y)$.

Comment: @zhoraster that's interesting. So if $h$ is compactly supported functions of $\Bbb{R}^2$ then linear combinations of functions of the form $f(x)g(y)$ satisfies $\Vert h-\sum fg\Vert_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes. For example, polynomials are such linear combinations.